# Shapefile Attribute table: Automatic numbering of points arranged in (non-orthogonal) row/line based blocks, by row order + from left to right

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, point, attribute-table, numbering

I have a Sentinel time series of several rasters, which contain reflection values for 10 Sentinel-bands. Now I'd like to excerpt these values for given points. The sample points are arranged in pixel grid based blocks, each consisting of 5 rows with 20 points per row (100 points in total). All blocks are embedded in one layer.

- There are normal, orthogonal arranged blocks.
- But there are also trapeze-like shifted blocks in different versions, e.g.:

  - 45°, **every** point shifted one pixel downwards
  - 26°, every **two** points shifted one pixel downwards
  - 17°, every **three** points shifted one pixel downwards

The image shows as an example the orthogonal and the 26°-shifted version.
[image]

Onto my issue:
The point-Shapefile attribute-table has 4 fields:
  Point-ID::::: Block number ::::: Row number ::::: Point number

Now, I want each point to be listed in the table - regardless of the block form - by the following principle:

- The numeration beginns for each block with the top point of the left side
- The numeration should then follow the first row rightwards, then the second row rightwards, ...
- ending at the lowest point of the right.

Based on the example image in the end like this:
[image]

As I have a lot of these blocks, here now my question:
Is there any option - instead of numerating manually point by point - to proceed the numbering automatically, **either after or with creation of the points** (by built-in tool, Add-on or python script,...)? 
 I am using QGis 3.16 / Win10